# Jquery mobile swipe left fires twice

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have a very simple use case.

On page init load a html.

```
 $(document).on('pageinit',function(){
                window.localStorage.setItem("page",'intro_1');                              
                $('#navigation_main').load('html/intro_1.html');

            });
```

On swipe just change the dom.

```
 var flag = 0;
              $("body").bind("swipeleft",function(event) {
                flag +=1;                               
                page = window.localStorage.getItem("page"); 
                alert(flag);            
                switch(page){
                    case 'intro_1':                         
                        window.localStorage.setItem("page",'intro_2');
                        $('#navigation_main').load('html/intro_2.html');                        
                        break;  

                    case 'intro_2':
                        window.localStorage.setItem("page",'challenges');
                        $('#navigation_main').load('html/challenges.html');                     
                        break;  

                    case 'challenges':
                        window.localStorage.setItem("page",'risk_areas');
                        $('#navigation_main').load('html/risk_areas.html');                     
                        break;

                    default:
                        window.localStorage.setItem("page",'intro_1');                              
                        $('#navigation_main').load('html/intro_1.html');
                        break;  
                }

            });
```

Now this swipe left is being fired twice, causing subsequent pages to be loaded. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you have event binded multiple times, It can be solved in few ways.

1. Use **$(body).unbind();** before binding an event. Unbind will remove all already binded events. Unfortunately this is not a good prevention because you are constantly bind/unbind thus causing a lot of processing overhead.
2. There is an alternative to using event bind/unbind, live/die and on/off. Instead of unbinding before you bind it again use jQuery event filter, it can be used to identify if event is already been bind. Don't forget to download it from link posted below (it is not a standard part of jQM).

   http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

   This is my usage example:

   ```
   $('#carousel div:Event(!click)').each(function(){
       //If click is not bind to #carousel div do something
   });
   ```

   I am using each because my carousel div has many inner blocks but principle is the same. If #carousel inner div elements don't have click event add them that event. In your case this will prevent multiple event binding.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `$("body").one` instead of `$("body").bind` so that it's only called once.

Comment: must be bound twice try $("body").die("swipeleft", <put your function here>); so that kills the first bound item, then add it.

Comment: This answer is old, but you meant `$("body").on`. That's "on", not "one".